# Escrever um novo html com js ou jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

eu queria saber de vocês se existe uma maneira de apresentar uma nova página html utilizando uma string contendo todo o conteúdo da nova página que estou tentando apresentar, o código esta abaixo:

```
$("#form").on('valid.fndtn.abide', function () {
        var data = $(this).serializeArray();
        sendAjax('index.php?uc=eventos&a=logView', 'POST', data, function (data) {
            try {
                var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                if (!data.status) {
                    alertify.error("A hora ou a Data inserida excede a hora e a data corrente! " +
                            "Você não pode ver resgistros do futuro!");
                }
            } catch (e) {
                document.open();
                document.write(data);
                document.close();
            }
        });
    });
```

este `document.write(data);` é onde escrevo uma nova pagina HTML com a string recebida do servidor, no firefox ela funciona em um primeiro momento mas se eu atualizo a página resultante ela quebra toda a formatação e o Chrome repete elementos, ou seja, não é uma alternativa viável, minha pergunta é, dentro daquele "data" tenho meu novo html em string como eu faço para mostrar o mesmo na janela do navegador sem usar o document.write.

Desde já obrigado pela atenção e ajuda.

Comment: Há duas variaveis data no seu código, a referencia dentro do catch está pegando a primeira, é isso mesmo?

Comment: quando faço `var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);` estou criando outra referencia de data na memória, então o data de fora do catch tem uma referência diferente do que está dentro, nomes iguais mais escopos diferentes e valores também, vou mudar isso pois causa confusão. Mas valeu a observação.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo, gostaria de primeiro lhe dá um pequeno conselho, tente não utilizar `try-catch` para controlar o fluxo da aplicação, afinal `try-catch` é para tratar erros, nada mais.

Quanto ao `document.write`, o ideal é criar um [`DocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) com a `DOMString` e adiciona-lo ao `body`.

```js
var form = document.getElementById("form");
form.addEventListener("valid.fndtn.abide", function (event) {
  var formData = new FormData(form);
  var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlHttp.open("POST", "index.php?uc=eventos&a=logView");
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function (event) {  
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {  
      if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {  
        var template = document.createElement("template");
        template.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        document.body.appendChild(template.content);
      } else {  
        alertify.error(xmlhttp.statusText);  
      }  
    }
  }
  xmlHttp.send(formData);
});
```

Comment: Pô valeu cara, eu tratei no servidor o conteúdo de retorno da body e voltou certinho, vou ter que fazer umas modificações para tratar as mensagem de erro mais agora está tranquilo, como não vou mais tentar escrever todos os elementos do zero o problema de quebra deve parar.

Answer (score 0):

Sim, é possível.

Com Js Puro:

```
document.getElementById("ID_DIV").innerHTML = "<input type='text'> </input>";
```

E com JQuery:

```
$("#ID_DIV").html("<input type='text'> </input>");
```

Comment: A premissa era essa mesmo, mas o problema era mais abrangente em termos de modificação da pagina atual, valeu pela atenção.